# Помогите растянуть высоту картинки в div'е

Tags: css, вёрстка, css3, bootstrap

Добавил в `div` картинку, наложил поверх текст, ещё блоки, но вот сама картинка отображается не во всю высоту. `height: 100%;` не помогает.

```css
.bg {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(/images/bg.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-color: #333;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 9em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid bg">
      <div class="center-block">
           <p class="text-uppercase" style="font-size:1.2em;color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);position:relative;text-align:center">dukascopy is looking for world</p>
           <h1 class="text-uppercase" style="font-size:10em;font-weight:400;letter-spacing:0.1em">virtuosos</h1>
           <div class="panel">
               <img src="images/Layer-221.png" style="align-self:center" alt="">
           </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Посмотрите, в chrome ctrl+shift+c может у некоторых блоков задан padding или margin, который не дает растянуться изображению, ну и у изображения надо сделать display:block т.к. по умолчанию он inline и свойство height на такие элементы не работает.

Comment: А можете загрузить изображение на этот сайт?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
background-size: cover
```